# When is $f(z)$ analytic in the neigbourhood of $z$ for some complex $z$ close to the real line?

Tags: complex-analysis, smooth-functions, analytic-continuation, lacunary-series

Let $f(x)$ be real-valued, 1-periodic, bounded and $C^{\infty}$ for real $x$.

When is $f(z)$ analytic in the neigbourhood of $z$ for some complex $z$ close to the real line ?

Notice this is similar to asking for lacunary series for a given $C^{\infty}$ boundary.

Comment: this is a bit unclear - I can see two answers possible at least depending on what you want; if the Fourier coefficients of $f$ are exponentially small $\hat f(n)=O(e^{-a|n|}), a >0$ then $f$ has an analytic extension in the neighborhood of the real line (on a strip actually); but also if $\hat f (n)=0, n <0$ then $f$ has an analytic extension to the lower plane easily seen if you put $w=e^{nz}$ so $f(w)=\sum_{n \ge 0}a_n w^n, |w|=1$ extends to $|w|<1$ so to $\Re  z<0$ - no smoothness condition needed on $f$, just integrability and $\hat f(n)=0, n<0$; similarly of course if $\hat f(n)=0, n>0$

Comment: @Conrad but not every $C^{\infty}$ is a fourier series ?

Comment: Every integrable periodic function is fourier series and if is $C^{\infty}$ (as periodic function of course) then the coefficients are $O(n^{-k})$ for every $k$

Comment: But not every function is equal to its fourier series, or is that irrelevant ?

Comment: A smooth function is definitely equal to its Fourier series; for just an integrable function with zero coefficients with negative index it's true that the analytic extension to the unit disc represents the original $f$ only in a summable sense usually but for smooth $f$ no problem; even $C^1$ function have Fourier series converging uniformly etc and $C^2$ is absolutely convergent too

Comment: @Conrad You can write up an answer based on your comments. I thought about it and any remaining questions are basicly fourier questions.